# Telerik Validation not working

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I have my code setup like this.

```
            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h5>Vendor:</h5>
                                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.item.ManufacturerID)
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "required",  @class = "fill" })
                                    .OptionLabel("Select Manufacturer")
                                    .BindTo(Model.VendorList)

                                )    
                             </div>
             </div>
```

When i try to submit this form, i get a javascript error

> An invalid form control with name='item.ManufacturerID' is not focusable.

I need to make this field required. Please help

Comment: Can you post your code that runs when you submit the form?

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. I will post it below. I appreciate your concern. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some time but i finally figure out the problem. The validation works for textboxes but you have to call the validator externally for dropdowns/ comboboxes for some reason which i am still trying to figure out. But the solution to the above problem is to create a JQuery function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkform').click(function (e) { // button that submits the form 
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit to check for validation
        var validator = $("#AddEquipmentForm").kendoValidator().data('kendoValidator'); // form name / id 
        validator.validate(); // check validation 
        if (validator.validate()) {
            $("#AddEquipmentForm").submit(); // if everything is valid, submit
        }

    })    
})
```